# binding data in a directive returns inconsistent values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have this wierd problem with binding data to a directive. this is how i declare my directive:

```
<my-directive data="myArray"></my-directive>
```

my directive code looks like:

```
angular.module('ngApp')
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope:{
            data: '='
        },
        template: '<div steps="data.length"></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope);
            console.log(scope.data);
        }
    };
});
```

in the first log, the data property is correct:
[screenshot of console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anA47.png)
but the [second log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Kyv.png) is undefined.

any idea why?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle or Plunkr to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution :

```
<my-directive data-example="myArray"></my-directive>
```

you should always name your variables `data-<name>`. This is far easier to maintain and this prevent errors with keywords like this one ;)

```
angular.module('ngApp')
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope:{
            data: '=example'
        },
        template: '<div steps="data.length"></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope);
            console.log(scope.data);
        }
    };
});
```

i hope this help,

Live example : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63ngx7sp/)

Comment: sorry, still the same. scope.data is undefined

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @hadiJZ and @Unex i figured it out:

my directive was nested in another directive. but the parent directive used the link function for the logic, since on creation it wasn't having child directives.

so moving the logic out to a controller solved my problem.
i figured it out when i added a $timeout to the child directive, and the log (scope.data) was correct.